# Formatting data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have read in each line of a data file with `n` lines into   an `n` length cell array in matlab.

A sample line, element of my cell array looks like

```
   ' 21, 0, '1 ',1 , 0.00000, 2, ' Sam ', 1, 1.0000 '
```

I want to form another cell-matrix with the above line  replaced by

```
21, 0, '1 ',1 , 0.00000, 2, ' Sam ', 1, 1.0000
```

i.e. essentially the outer quotes removed. So this row should be of length 9.

How should I do this?

Comment: Is it just an ascii file? can you give an example of more than just that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the outer quotes, apply `regexprep` on your cell array (let's denote it `C`):

```
regexprep(C, '^\s*''\s*(.*)\s*''\s*', '$1');
```

**P. S:**
You should probably be better off reading the input file without those quotes in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If 'temp' is a string element of a cell array at the position n and m

```
temp = var_cell{n,m}
```

you can remove the elements at both the sides in this way :

```
temp2 = temp(2:length(temp)-1)
var_cell{n,m} = temp2
```

if you want to remove also the white spaces:

```
temp2 = temp(3:length(temp)-2)
var_cell{n,m} = temp2
```

Comment: you can define also a new cell if you do not want to use the old one with the comand new_cell = cell(m,n)

consider to mark the answer with the green V if it is useful